# What's the best T-SQL syntax to filter for an ID that has a count of X or at least X or at most X in a joined table?

Tags: t-sql, join, filter, count, filtering

What's the best way to do something like this in T-SQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM Members,
INNER JOIN Comments ON Members.MemberId = Comments.MemberId
WHERE COUNT(Comments.CommentId) > 100
```

Trying to get the members who have commented more than 100 times. This is obviously invalid code but what's the best way to write this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get you what you're after.  I'm not saying this is the absolutely best way of doing it, but it's unlikely you'll find anything better.

```
SELECT ID
FROM   Members
INNER JOIN Comments
ON Members.MemberId = Comments.MemberId
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using a subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.ID
FROM Members m
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(c.CommentID)
       FROM Comments c
       WHERE c.MemberID = m.MemberID) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT ID
FROM Members
INNER JOIN (SELECT MemberID FROM Comments 
     GROUP BY MemberID HAVING COUNT(CommentId) > 100) 
AS CommentCount ON Members.MemberID = CommentCount.CommentID
```

Comment: Me too.  I also like putting `WHERE` after `GROUP BY`.  :)